# htaccess rule for multiple optional and default query parameters

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, query-string

I have the following htaccess rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^licitatii/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ licitatii.php?orderBy=$1&orderByType=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^licitatii/([^/]*)/?$ licitatii.php?orderBy=$1&orderByType=asc [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^licitatii licitatii.php?orderBy=licitatii_date&orderByType=asc [NC,L,QSA]
```

And when i use an anchor tag like this

```
<a href="/licitatii/licitatii_date/asc">Click</a>
```

nothing happens with the query parameters and with the url.

Edit:
I do not get 404 but after I go to this url '/licitatii/licitatii-date/asc/' i get this
[image]

instead of this

[image]

Therefore, the url is changed but there is not the provided output and it behave like I accessed an inexistent page (rule in htaccess)
And this is my modified htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
Options -MultiViews
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f

RewriteRule ^cauta/([a-z0-9\+]+)-([a-z0-9\+]+)-([a-z0-9\+]+)-([a-z0-9\+]+)-([a-z0-9\+]+)-pag([0-9]+)$ cautaLucrare?cautaCategorie=$1&keyWord=$2&cautaDataFrom=$3&cautaDataTo=$4&location=$5&pager=$6 [QSA,L]
#RewriteRule ^cauta/([a-z0-9\+]+)-([a-z0-9\+]+)-([a-z0-9\+]+)-pag([0-9]+)$ cautaLucrare.php?tip_ev=$1&numar_persoane=$2&numar_stele=$3&pager=$4 [QSA,L]


RewriteRule ^adauga_anunt1 landings/landing2.php?source=adwordsLanding2 [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^adauga_anunt cumFunctioneaza.php [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9a-z-/]+)-([0-9]+) blog.php?title=$1&idArt=$2 [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^blog blog.php [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^cont/detalii detalii.php [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^cont/parola-noua parolaNoua.php [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^cont/istoric istoric.php [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^cont/oferte-acceptate oferteAcceptate.php [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^login-fb loginM.php?source=fb [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^adauga-anunt landings/landing1.php?source=adwordsLanding1 [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^login loginM.php [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^facebook loginFB.php [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^cont-activat contActivat.php [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^parola-uitata parolaUitata.php [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^adauga-lucrare adaugaLucrare.php [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^adauga2 adaugaLucrare2.php [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^inregistreaza-prestator inregPrest.php [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^inregistreaza-beneficiar inregBen.php [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^contact contact.php [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^termeni-si-conditii tandc.php [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^despre-noi despre2.php [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^cauta-lucrare cautaLucrare2.php [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^cauta cautaLucrare2.php [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^admin/functii admin.php [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^admin/statistici statistici.php [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^logout logout.php [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^lucrari-active lucrariActive.php [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^cont/lucrari-active2 lucrariActive2.php [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^licitatii/([^/]+)?/([^/]+)?/$ licitatii.php?orderBy=$1&orderByType=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^licitatii/([^/]+)?/$ licitatii.php?orderBy=$1 [NC,L,QSA]   

RewriteRule ^licitatii licitatii.php [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^contul-meu cont.php [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^cont2 cont2.php [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^cont/mesaj-([0-9]+) mesaj.php?id_mesaj=$1 [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^cont/mesaje-([0-9]+) mesaje.php?pager=$1 [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^cont/mesaje mesaje.php [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^cum-functioneaza cumFunctioneaza.php [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^edit-([0-9]+) editAdd.php?idAnunt=$1 [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^edit-licitatie-([0-9]+) editOff.php?idLic=$1 [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z-/\)\(!?]+)-([0-9]+) page2.php?anuntTitlu=$1&idAnuntToShow=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z-/]+)-([0-9]+) cautaLucrare2.php?anuntTitlu=$1&idAnuntToShow=$2 [NC,L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^categorii/([0-9a-z-/]+) categories.php?categoryToShow=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Later edit:
After a little research when i access this url `licitatii/licitatii-date/asc` it match this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z-/]+) categories.php?categoryToShow=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

instead of this rules:

```
RewriteRule ^licitatii/([a-z-A-Z-0-9-]+)/([^/]+)/?$ licitatii.php?orderBy=$1&orderByType=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^licitatii/([a-z-A-Z-0-9-]+)/?$ licitatii.php?orderBy=$1 [NC,L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^licitatii/?$ licitatii.php? [NC,L,QSA]
```

How can i prevent matching the above rule?

Edit:
I get a 302 after I enter the url. The request is in the following image:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean nothing happens? Do you get a 404 response?

Comment: after I click the link it redirects me to the same page and url looks like "/licitatii". It does not update the query parameters

Comment: Just to be clear, you ARE getting the query parameters, but they don't change when you change the URL?

Comment: Yes, when i click the anchor tag with that link, the query parameters are the defaults, and when i write by myself the url it redirects me to the home page

Comment: Well, with `/licitatii/licitatii_date/asc` you get the same as if you put /licitatii/, don't you? What happens if you change the anchor to /licitatii/licitatii_date2/asc2?

Comment: the same behavior, the query parameters are not updating. it is exactly the same as /licitatii/

Comment: I asume you have `RewriteEngine On` before all the rules? (just narrowing it down)

Comment: Yes, i have a lot of rewrite rules but only those have a strange behavior

Answer (score 1):

Have it this way with `MultiViews` turned off, using anchor in 3rd rule and using `+` quantifier instead of `*`:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^licitatii/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ licitatii.php?orderBy=$1&orderByType=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^licitatii/([^/]+)/?$ licitatii.php?orderBy=$1&orderByType=asc [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^licitatii/?$ licitatii.php?orderBy=licitatii_date&orderByType=asc [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you! I rewrite the rules based on your answer and know it goes to the desired link but it doesn't find the specified file, can you tell me how the rules should be to accept as a query parameter multiple words separated by '-'. i tried "^licitatii/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/"

Comment: Sorry, a part of the file is not in the code preview, is a little above, i will try your sollution and i will edit this after

Comment: Hello it is possible that with this URL `licitatii\licitatii-date\asc` to enter on this htaccess rule? `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z-/]+) categories.php?categoryToShow=$1 [NC,L,QSA]` because I noticed that it tries to show a category with that name

Comment: Do one thing. Rename your .htaccess to something else. And keep only the code I suggested in .htaccess and then use `/licitatii/licitatii-date/asc/` to test.

Comment: I renamed my file and created a new one but after i enter the link it redirects me to the homepage

Comment: As you can see there is no redirect flag anywhere in my answer so I suspect you have some local code/config issue. When you enter `example.com/licitatii/licitatii-date/desc/` in browser, then does URL also change in browser?

Comment: Yes, it goes to example.com

Comment: I edited the issue and i get a 301/302 redirect in browser

Comment: You can see there is no 301/302 in my suggested rules. So clearly you have some code in your `licitatii.php` doing these redirects.